# List of strings in string

Tags: python

How can I write expression in python that checks if string contains any of strings provided.
Something like this:

```
s = 'winter summer spring fall'

# i like fall and spring
i_like = 'fall', 'spring' in s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in `any` function:

```
i_like = any(i in s for i in ('fall', 'spring'))
```

This checks if any of the elements in the tuple are in the string.

Comment: Thank you! I can use 'any' for any of the keywords.